Pentaho Kettle issue handling Oracle xmltype field synchronization
All the values of xmltype field are changeed to null when synchronizing from Oracle to Oracle using Pentaho Kettle.
error
I have an Oracle table containing xmltype field like following
create table t1(
id number(20,0)
,col xmltype
)

and I tried synchroizing its data into my destination table which is also in Oracle.
I designed a workflow in kettle Spoon
Spoon workflow
The sql query in table_in is as this:
select id
      , col
 from t1

where there is no transformation.
When I previewed the data I found the values of column col are all null. after running the workflow, all the values of col in destination table all null too.
Any help to show me how to handle this issue?
